# How to buy a location quota for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

We have more than 1,000,000 positioning requests every day, so the free quota is not enough. I have contacted the salesperson’s email before but did not respond. I would like to ask how to improve the positioning quota.

Comment: As far as I know there are no any daily quota anymore. When Google introduced Google Maps Platform in July 2018 they removed a daily quota, so you shouldn't have any issue with this. However they still have a QPS quota. You can send 50 requests per second. Have a look at the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing